# GeoIP com While

Tags: php

Tenho este código abaixo, e um arquivo TXT com todos os IP's. No o codigo abaixo tem que setar o IP diretamente para pegar a localização do mesmo, porem preciso que isso seja automatizado, tenho os Ip's em um arquivo chamado ip.txt, precisava criar um while, for etc para que os IP's sejam lidos e com o echo trazer o resultado. Já tentei algumas formas sem sucesso, poderiam me ajudar?

```
    <?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';


   $gi = 


 geoip_open("/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/GeoLiteCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);





 echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\t" .
      geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "80.24.24.24") . "\n";
 echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "201.210.254.45") . "\t" .
      geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "201.210.254.45") . "\n";
 echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, "124.253.51.88") . "\t" .
     geoip_country_name_by_addr($gi, "124.253.51.88") . "\n";

     geoip_close($gi);


      ?>
```

Comment: Como estão os dados no `.txt`?

Comment: Estão com os Ips um de baixo do outro, sem nenhuma outra informação, apenas os Ip's.

Comment: Desculpe, editei meu texto, no TXT não existe os países e siglas, e sim apenas os Ips.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) e itere:

```
$ips = file('ips.txt');

$gi = geoip_open("/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/GeoLiteCity.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);

foreach($ips as $ip) {
    echo geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip) . "\t";
}

geoip_close($gi);
```

Comment: Boa Tarde @Marcelo, usei o seu exemplo agora, porem, ele apenas lê o "\t"  e o o retorno é um  echo pulando uma linha, sem voltar nenhuma informação. Se eu colocar no lugar da variável $ip, um IP qualquer, ex: (24.24.24.24) ele retorna vários US, que é a localização deste IP. Sabe o motivo?

Comment: Dê um `var_dump($ips)` e mostra qual o resultado.

Comment: Desculpe, sou um pouco leigo ainda em PHP, dou este var_dump fora do foreach certo? se for o resultado é: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in

Comment: O `var_dump($ips);` vai logo após o `$ips = file('ips.txt');`

Comment: [657]=>
  string(14) "191.190.58.56
"
  [658]=>
  string(16) "204.191.149.146
"
  [659]=>
  string(13) "179.233.5.94
"
  [660]=>
  string(14) "203.86.153.18
"
  [661]=>
  string(15) "177.156.150.97
"
  [662]=>
  string(15) "177.156.150.97
"
  [663]=>
  string(13) "187.37.83.76
"
  [664]=>
  string(16) "220.143.174.218
"
  [665]=>
  string(15) "74.101.206.183
"
  [666]=>
  string(14) "179.218.2.171
"
  [667]=>
  string(14) "12.249.95.238

Comment: A saída está correta, dentro do `foreach`, como é a saída de `var_dump($ip);`?

Comment: com var_dump($ip) é :   PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ip in /home/mmatos/projetos/projetospammer/ipinfo.php on line 8
NULL

Comment: Coloquei o var_dump dentro do foreach e o resultado é :    string(16) "220.143.174.218
"
 string(15) "74.101.206.183
"
 string(14) "179.218.2.171
"
 string(14) "12.249.95.238